# Clojure Group Sequential Occurrences - Improve Function

Tags: algorithm, clojure

I'm trying to group items that appear directly beside each other, so long as they are each in a given "white-list".  Groupings must have at least two or more items to be included.

For example, first arg is the collection, second arg the whitelist.

```
(group-sequential [1 2 3 4 5] [2 3])
>> ((2 3))

(group-sequential ["The" "quick" "brown" "healthy" "fox" "jumped" "over" "the" "fence"] 
                  ["quick" "brown" "over" "fox" "jumped"])
>> (("quick" "brown") ("fox" "jumped" "over"))

(group-sequential [1 2 3 4 5 6 7] [2 3 6])
>> ((2 3))
```

This is what I've come up with:

```
(defn group-sequential
  [haystack needles]
  (loop [l haystack acc '()]
    (let [[curr more] (split-with #(some #{%} needles) l)]
      (if (< (count curr) 2)
        (if (empty? more) acc (recur (rest more) acc))
        (recur (rest more) (cons curr acc))))))
```

It works, but is pretty ugly.   I wonder if there's a much simpler idiomatic way to do it in Clojure?  (You should have seen the fn before I discovered split-with :)

I bet there's a nice one-liner with partition-by or something, but it's late and I can't quite seem to make it work.

Comment: what is the logic that determins that "brown" and "fox" are split?

Comment: Ah, you're right @noisesmith.  That's a typo. I'll add in "healthy" in between to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(defn group-sequential [coll white] 
  (->> coll
       (map (set white))
       (partition-by nil?)
       (filter (comp first next))))
```

... a tidier version of [Diego Basch's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26352825/1562315).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my first attempt:

```
(defn group-sequential [xs wl]
  (let [s (set wl)
        f (map #(if (s %) %) xs)
        xs' (partition-by nil? f)]
    (remove #(or (nil? (first %)) (= 1 (count %))) xs')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I realized partition-by is pretty close to what I'm looking for, so I created this function which seems a lot more in line with the core stuff.

```
(defn partition-if
  "Returns a lazy seq of partitions of items that match the filter"
  [pred coll]
  (lazy-seq
   (when-let [s (seq coll)]
     (let [[in more0] (split-with pred s)
           [out more] (split-with (complement pred) more0)]
       (if (empty? in)
         (partition-if pred more)
         (cons in (partition-if pred more)))))))

(partition-if #(some #{%} [2 3 6]) [1 2 3 4 5 6 7])
>> ((2 3))
```

Comment: Suggest you remove the `(< (count in) 2)` condition from the putative general function `partition-if`. It sticks out like a sore thumb, and isn't in the descriptive comment. You can always filter the result accordingly.

Comment: Good point @Thumbnail.  I changed it to filter empty?, since sometimes you'll get (() (3 4)) in the results, which I don't think is expected even in the general case.  Thoughts?

Comment: Sound. The one empty partition occurs initially whenever `(not (pred (first coll)))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn group-sequential
  [coll matches]
  (let [matches-set (set matches)]
    (->> (partition-by (partial contains? matches-set) coll)
         (filter #(clojure.set/subset? % matches-set))
         (remove #(< (count %) 2)))))
```